# Android: Insert data into sql server database using webservices

Tags: android

I have done reading of resultset and displaying it on `ListFragment` from SQL Server database using Java Servlet and jtds driver. This was done using JSON.

Now please guide me how to do Insert\Delete\Update operations using JSON.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by the following code, and parsed `JSON` using `JSONParser`.

```
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("my_url");
    List parameters = new ArrayList(2);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("par_1", "1");
    jsonObject.put("par_2", "2");
    jsonObject.put("par_3", "3");
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "par_action"));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonObject.toString()));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    Log.v("Server Application", EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())+" "+jsonObject.toString());

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.e("Server Application", "Error: " + e);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e("Server Application", "Error: " + e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Server Application", "Error: " + e);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```